# Angular Links in view not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am just beginning to experiment with AngularJS and have come across a problem.

My main page renders a `<ng-view>` element and I have set up the following routes:

```
(function () {
   var routes = function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
         when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'Home/Overview',
            controller: 'OverviewPageController'
         })
         .when('/Issue/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'Home/Issue'
         })
         .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
   }

   routes.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];

   angular.module('PublicationSchedulerApp')
      .config(routes);

}());
```

If I add a link tag outside of the `<ng-view>`:

```
<a ng-href="#/Issue/123">Issue</a>
```

The 'Issue' page is loaded into the view as expected.

In my case however, the Overview controller loads some data via an asynchronous Ajax call and then renders a table with a custom directive which, in turn, uses `<ng-repeat>`.  If I create the same link within this directive/table:

```
<tr ng-repeat="issue in issues">
   <td>
      <a ng-href="#/issue/{{ issue.issueId }}">{{ issue.subject }}</a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

The routing doesn't work.  As you can see, I have played around with changing the link attribute from `href` to `ng-href` but this doesn't seem to make any difference.  I am guessing that the asynchronous loading of the data is somehow breaking the routing, but I am not sure how to fix it.  A couple of posts suggested that I reload the $route after the data load:

```
angular.module('PublicationSchedulerApp')
.run(['$route', function ($route) {
   $route.reload();
}]);
```

but this didn't appear to make any difference either.

Any help would be much appreciated - thanks.

Comment: `.when('/Issue/:id', {` => shouldn't "Issue" be non capitalized, or your link capitalized?

Comment: you can see what the link is being generated in anchor tag via inspecting element in browser. Try checking that dynamic link

Comment: link is lowercase, router is wordcase

Comment: I'm an idiot - I have spent hours looking at this and it never occurred to me that routes were case sensitive at the Angular/JavaScript level - which, of course, makes obvious sense.  Thank you for your help.  Thomas or CharlieTfl if you want to post this as the answer, I would be happy to mark it up.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular, routes are case sensitive. So make sure that your links match your route.

```
<tr ng-repeat="issue in issues">
   <td>
      <a ng-href="#/Issue/{{ issue.issueId }}">{{ issue.subject }}</a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

You can also use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), that way you will be able to create your links with state names rather than URLs (easier to maintain and less error-prone).

Comment: Thank you Thomas - I'll definitely check out ui-router